# NSMutableArray save all values of all views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

I have 2 viewControllers, with one TableView that contains a textView inside a row.

**ViewControllerOne.h** / **ViewControllerSecond.h** (Same codes)

```
UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayFields;
```

**ViewControllerOne.m**

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *searchStr = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    self.arrayFields[0] = searchStr;

    return YES;
}
```

**ViewControllerSecond.m**

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {
        NSString *searchStr = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

        self.arrayFields[1] = searchStr;

        return YES;
    }
```

When the app run, the ViewControllerOne is opened and I write a text inside my textView, now to go to ViewControllerSecond I press a button that exists in my navigationBar:

```
-(void)next{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    ViewControllerSecond *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileToHome4"];
    [self setAnimation];
    lvc.arrayFields = self.arrayFields;
}
```

With this code I can pass my array to the next view. When next view appear I can write a text inside my another textView. Great! Lets click in my back button that exists in my navigationBar to back to my ViewControllerOne:

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

In my ViewControllerOne I have a save button in my navigationBar, when the user press this button the console show me the content inside my array... But is strange... When I do this I can see 2 index with two texts!

In my mind when I pop my ViewControllerSecond the arrayFields will dealloc and the index 1 have never existed, and when I press the save button in my ViewControllerOne the correct would be:

> "Text 1"

Not:

> "Text 1" "Text 2"

But why this is happening? (since I not return the array to my first view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You second view controller's arrayFields is a strong reference to your first view controller's. It is passed by reference, not as a copy. In your ViewControllerOne's `next` method, change `lvc.arrayFields = self.arrayFields;` to `lvc.arrayFields = [self.arrayFields copy];`

Comment: in my case is great doing in this format, because I don't need to return my array... I only asked because I don't understand why this occurred, Thanks :D